# Woocommerce hide specific content to users that are not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide the following content that's inside of content-product.php to guest users (make it invisible to users that are not registered):

```
<?php if( get_field('___unit_price') ): ?>
<p>Unit Price: $<?php the_field('___unit_price'); ?></p>
```

For the life of me I can't get it to hide. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more conditional logic.

```
<?php if( get_field('___unit_price') ): ?>
<p>Unit Price: $<?php the_field('___unit_price'); ?></p>
```

only checks if the `get_field()` function returns a value, but you also want to check if the user is logged in. Conveniently, WordPress has a function called [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) that checks exactly that.

```
<?php if( is_user_logged_in() && get_field('___unit_price') ): ?>
<p>Unit Price: $<?php the_field('___unit_price'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That did it. On one instance I was close but I think I messed the code up. Yours did the trick!!!